# How to display immediately an active image from carousel to my 2nd div if I click next/ previous?

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem displaying an active image from carousel to my 2nd div when I click next/ previous. Looks like it's delayed when I click next/ previous.

```js
function strapActiveImage() {
        var activeElImgSrc = document.querySelector('div#strap_carousel>div.carousel-inner>.carousel-item.active > img').getAttribute('src');
        document.getElementById('strap_logo').src = activeElImgSrc;
        document.getElementById('strap_logo2').src = activeElImgSrc;

    }
```

```html
    <!-- STRAP -->
    <div class="justify-content-center body-inner">
        <div class="personalize-item-title left-align bold">
            <span>STRAP</span>
        </div>
        <!-- CarouselBegin -->
        <div id="strap_carousel" data-interval="false" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="stap_design/strap_1.png" class="personalize-left-strap margin-top">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="stap_design/strap_2.png" class="personalize-left-strap margin-top">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#strap_carousel" role="button" onclick="strapActiveImage()" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#strap_carousel" onclick="strapActiveImage()" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <span>LEATHER</span>
        <!-- CarouselEnd-->
    </div>
    <!-- STRAP END -->
<div class="justify-content-center body-inner">
    <img src = "stap_design/strap_1.png" class="strap_display" id="strap_logo">
    <img src="stap_design/strap_1.png" class="strap_display2" id="strap_logo2">
</div>
```

Comment: Its in the css, look for `transition` and `transform` within the carousel, set them to none

Comment: I'll try @Pavlo. Thanks for the answer bdw.

Comment: Perhaps transition and transform doesn't solve my problem either @Pavlo but thanks to your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of those who are looking for an answer for a question/ problem like this one, I was able to solve my own problem by adding an onload="strapActiveImage()" to the image tag (where display is happening). Here is the code:

```js
function strapActiveImage() {
        var activeElImgSrc = document.querySelector('div#strap_carousel>div.carousel-inner>.carousel-item.active > img').getAttribute('src');
        document.getElementById('strap_logo').src = activeElImgSrc;
        document.getElementById('strap_logo2').src = activeElImgSrc;

    }
```

```html
    <!-- STRAP -->
    <div class="justify-content-center body-inner">
        <div class="personalize-item-title left-align bold">
            <span>STRAP</span>
        </div>
        <!-- CarouselBegin -->
        <div id="strap_carousel" data-interval="false" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="stap_design/strap_1.png" class="personalize-left-strap margin-top">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="stap_design/strap_2.png" class="personalize-left-strap margin-top">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#strap_carousel" role="button" onclick="strapActiveImage()" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#strap_carousel" onclick="strapActiveImage()" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <span>LEATHER</span>
        <!-- CarouselEnd-->
    </div>
    <!-- STRAP END -->
<div class="justify-content-center body-inner">
    <img src = "stap_design/strap_1.png" class="strap_display" id="strap_logo" onload="strapActiveImage()">
    <img src="stap_design/strap_1.png" class="strap_display2" id="strap_logo2" onload="strapActiveImage()">
</div>
```